# How can I add an image into a tableview "header"?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `UITableView` where I am displaying a list of data.  I would like to have a logo instead of just text for the header portion of the view.  The code below gives me just the text.

Any ideas on how to get the image in there?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self. = @"Videos";
```

Comment: I just realized, it's not clear if you want the entire table's header (there's only one, above the first cell) or the section headers (one per section, floating above the first cell).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  Yea, I want it to be above the first cell.

Comment: OK, what you want is an image in the UINavigationBar. That's different from the table view header or section headers, which are both part of the UITableView and will scroll around with its content. Tom Harrington's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an icon in the navigation bar (basically what the Facebook app does) use the navigationItem's titleView property.  You can put an arbitrary UIView there, and a UIImageView with the logo on a transparent background would give the same effect that Facebook uses.  Do this in viewDidLoad and you're set.

Any view controller can use a UINavigationItem, so if you're not using a navigation controller you should still be able to get one.

Alternately, just add a UIToolbar wherever it makes sense, and give it a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view set to a UIImageView.

Answer (score 4):

Something like that:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 69.0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 69.0)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"header1" ofType: @"png"]]];
    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: This will put the image on the header of every section, not the table header.